# Can't make Visual Studio 2010 XNA Windows Game project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xna, project-template

I can't make a Visual Studio 2010 XNA Windows Game project. When I do, I receive the following error message:

[image: Error message]

Now, I already tried running "devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates" with no luck. This command executes just fine, but all it does is to create duplicates of the already existing "XNA Windows Game" project templates.

Upon opening these duplicates, I get an object null reference exception from Visual Studio.

What's going on? All of this worked just 1 month ago. Since then, I've been doing some development with Windows Phone Mango SDK 7.1 RC. Could this be it? I'd be very unhappy to uninstall this in order to get it to work.

Please help me.

Comment: I think its best to uninstall and then reinstall.

Comment: That would tear my soul apart. There's got to be a better way.

Comment: If you try reinstalling the Mango SDK and choose the Repair option, does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have zipped up the XNA C# Project templates from my Visual Studio folder.

Unzip these into:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VPDExpressExtensions\Microsoft\XNA 
Game Studio 4.0\ProjectTemplates\CSharp* or the equivalent location on your machine.

The file can be found here: [XNA C# Project Templates](http://www.sendspace.com/file/ng6i48)

Let me know if this solves your issue.